# Multiple excel sheets import/export to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, export-to-excel

I have to export SQL Serverdata to Excel and edit (make a few changes) later restore it in the data in SQL Server database itself. I have tried doing this manually but can I do this task using SSIS or some other way because I have to do this several times a day.

Googled for this all that I could find was using SSIS which has ability to export/import data of 1 sheet not multiple sheets

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSIS, in the Excel Source component, you can simply specify the sheet name. You can have multiple Excel Components, or programmatically change the sheet name inside a loop.

Comment: Is there a way to achive this without using SSIS.

Comment: You could do it using OpenRowSet: SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Source\Addresses.xls',
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')